# elasticsearch aggregations by user defined group

Tags: elasticsearch

Let's say I have these data in ES.

```
| KEY        | value       |
|:-----------|------------:|
| A          |            1|
| A          |            2|
| B          |            2| 
| C          |            3|   
| D          |            4| 
| E          |            5|  
| E          |            5|  
| F          |            6|
```

I use this

```
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "filtered" : {
      "query" : {
          "match_all" : {} 
      },
      "filter" : {
        "bool" : {
          "must" : [
            {"terms": {"key": ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"]}}
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs" : {
    "sum_value" : {
      "terms" : { "field" : "key" },
      "aggs" : {
        "sum_value" : { "sum" : { "field" : "value" } }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

to get the sum of the same key, the results would look like this:

```
"sum_uv": {
  "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
  "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
  "buckets": [
    {
      "key": "A",
      "doc_count": 2,
      "sum_value": {
        "value": 3
      }
    }
    ....
  ]
}
```

But now, I want to sum all the elements that in the same group, for example, I have a mapping data, which tells me the group information:

```
group1 = [A, B, C]
group2 = [D, E, F]
.....
```

I think I need a nested aggregation for the purpose, but I have no idea to do this.

The result would look like this:

```
sum_group1 = 8
sum_group2 = 20
......
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least two ways of doing this:

1. If the groups are fixed, you can add the group name to each document and then aggregate first on group, then on values.
2. If you want a more dynamic approach, you can use filter + regexp to group the results. See example here: https://www.elastic.co/blog/quick-tips-regex-filter-buckets

two examples using filters:

## 1

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "groups": {
      "filters": {
        "filters": {
          "group1": { "terms": { "key": [ "A","B","C" ] } },
          "group2": { "terms": { "key": [ "D","E","F" ] } }
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "groupsum": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "key"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

## 2

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "match_all": { }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "group1": {
      "filter": {
        "terms": {
          "key": [ "A", "B", "C" ]
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "group1sum": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "value"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "group2": {
      "filter": {
        "terms": {
          "key": [ "D", "E", "F" ]
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "group2sum": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "value"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, But the situation is I can't add anything to the document and the group relation data are fetching from another database. There is no any pattern of the group.

Comment: @JasonYoung Added example using filter aggregations. Is this the kind of behaviour you were asking for?